# What does "90m-strong" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

"Goumin, a pet-services portal, says China has 73.5m cat- or dog-owners, a group approaching the size of the 90m-strong Communist Party." What does "90m-strong" mean here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 feet *long* = ten feet *in length*

10 feet *high* = ten feet *in height*

10 feet *wide* = ten feet *in width*

10 feet *deep* = ten feet *in depth*

10 inches *thick* = 10 inches *in thickness*

a million *strong* = a million *in strength*

And the "strength" of a group is normally expressed in how many individuals it contains.

> An army 10,000 strong marched on the city.

90m is an abbreviation for 90 million.

So "the 90m-strong Communist Party" means "the Communist Party, which has 90 million members". Note that the hyphen is unusual; normally one would just write "90m strong".

Comment: I suggest you address the "90m" part of the question as well.

Comment: @Old Pro: You should feel free to do that yourself if you think the other answers haven't addressed it to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Strength here implies size, as it does for the thickness of wooden boards, where the strength is significantly depending on size. Some words for crowds, and people, like e.g. German *deutsch*, are supposed to be from a root meaning strength. Also compare string (for the audible similarity) vs band and bond, for example. Also compare **mighty.**

And *90 m* means ninety million.